# How do apps like sHealth connect and get data from bluetooth devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to develop an android application, which will connect and get the data from bluetooth devices such as bluetooth weight scale or bluetooth blood pressure monitor. 
What is a possible and efficient way to communicate with most bluetooth devices in android? For example sHealth how manages to do so?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as your question in its current state will most likely not get any good answers

Comment: They are Bluetooth LE `peripheral devices` acting as a `GATT server` having `characteristics` to read and your phone is a `central device` acting as a `GATT client` connecting to the server. You can start from [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). That's the basic idea and if you come up with more specific problems you can then ask more specific questions. (And get more specific answers.)

Comment: you should find the API documentation for this devices. Only the manufacturer knows how to work with their devices

Comment: Actually there are [standardized profiles for many types of devices](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications) and not everything is purely manufacturer specific.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know about Bluetooth LE but it works only with Bluetooth LE devices. I want something to work with all bluetooth devices if it's possible. Then, I guess there should be a different implementation for different types of devices...

Comment: Sorry my question isn't very specific because I don't know what "methods" I should use for such an application. Thus, I need some guidelines and suggestions.